# Where can I find databases in .rdf or in .ttl format

Tags: database, sparql, rdf

I have to make web application with rdf and sparql and I need database in rdf/xml or in ttl format but I can not find. I thought about music or movies or books database but I did'nt find if you know please tell me where can I find databases?

Answer (score 3):

**[Information Retrieval Dataset - Internet Movie Database (IMDB)](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/rth2kr5hxf/2)**

**Description**

This dataset was constructed for an Information Retrieval research project to obtain a master's degree at the Federal University of Rio de Janeiro (UFRJ). It consists of a collection of nearly 115,000 documents in XML format, being a subset of the Internet Movie Database (IMDB). Each XML file contains the following information about one movie in the collection: · ID · Title · Year · Country · Actors (and their roles) · Actresses (and their roles) · Genre · Color Info · Language · Sound Info · Directors · Writers · Composers · Certificates (by country) · Duration · Shooting location (cities and countries) · Editors · Release date (by country) · Producers · Type (film, TV series, etc.)

---

**[Books XML](https://github.com/zygmuntz/goodbooks-10k/tree/master/books_xml)**

The archive contains 10000 XML files. One of them is available as books_xml/sample_book.xml.

---

**[DataSetRDFDumps](https://www.w3.org/wiki/DataSetRDFDumps)**

Linked Data Sets (i.e., with Dereferenceable URIs) available as RDF Dumps

Answer (score 1):

You can query DBPedia yourself, and ask it for information about certain Musicians.

The shell command

`curl -sL -H "Accept: text/turtle" "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Iggy_Pop"`

would return about 500 triples about the Singer-Songwriter Iggy Pop.
You can save them into a file, and then continue with the next curl command, submitting a query for another musician or music style, or whatever.

A related command such as

`curl -sL -H "Accept: application/json" https://dbpedia.org/resource/Iggy_Pop   | jq '. | keys_unsorted ' | jq .`  would return a list of ~150 URLs which can be used to gather more inforation about all things related to Iggy. Always append the query results to the same .ttl file

In rather short time you could create your own knowledge graph.

Bulk-Load the ttl file into a triple store . Many triple stores support the  SPARQL  LOAD command.

```
LOAD  
<file:/var/tmp/shared-files/iggy_pop_data.ttl>
INTO GRAPH <iggy>
```

Then you can run SPARQL queries.